# PrettyTable: "if len(self._rows) in (0, len(column)): AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_rows'"

Tags: python-3.x, prettytable

I'm trying to make a basic table by using the documentation.
This is my version of the code:

```
from prettytable import *

table = PrettyTable

table.add_column("", "Pokemon Name", ["Pikachu", "Squirtle", "Charmander"]) 
table.add_column("", "Type", ["Electric Type", "Water Type", "Fire Type"])

print(table)
```

I have tried removing, and reinstalling prettytable, but the problem still persists.

```
if len(self._rows) in (0, len(column)):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_rows'
```

Is there anything else I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to instantiate an object in python is
`table = PrettyTable()`

Then change your code for the following:

```
table.add_column("Pokemon Name", ["Pikachu", "Squirtle", "Charmander"]) 
table.add_column("Type", ["Electric Type", "Water Type", "Fire Type"])

print(table)
```

The error was coming from the fact that you where passing `self` as `""`

Comment: tysm! This helped so much!